# how to format month/day for 2 digits in mule4?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft, mule-esb

Im trying to create my filename in s3 with month/date format.
I dont want May to be printed as 5. It has to be '05'
I tried

```
  now().month as Number {format: "00"}
```

and

```
now().month as Number {format: "##"}
```

Both prints **5**. not as **05**.

```
<set-variable value="#[now().year ++ '/' ++ now().month as Number {format: &quot;00&quot;}++ '/'++ now().day as Number {format: &quot;##&quot;} ++'/'++ now() as String {format: &quot;yyyyMMdd_HHmmss&quot;} ++&quot;.json&quot;]"  doc:name="S3-filename" doc:id="ff101e31-4f6c-45f5-9669-a60fbc32204e" variableName="s3filename"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont's do multiple transformations to date, to number, to string. Transform directly to string. Pay attention that Month is MM (upper case) and minutes are mm (lower case)

https://simpleflatservice.com/mule4/Date_format.html

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
now() as String {format: "MM"}
```

[image]